# color rows on table (Tabu package)

Tags: tables, color, tabularx, tabu

I am writing a table with colored rows using the `tabu`package (`2.10`). For example

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{tabu}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\begin{document}
\begin{table}
    \rowcolors{2}{red}{blue}
    \begin{tabu}{cc}
        \toprule
        Row1 & A \\
        Row2 & B \\
        Row3 & C \\
        \bottomrule
    \end{tabu}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

I have also tried with `\taburowcolors 2{red ... blue}` but **the colors never show up at all.**

I am aware of the issue at the github repo https://github.com/tabu-fixed/tabu/issues and even after manually updating to the `2.10` release, the problem still persists for me.

Does anyone know if the problem has been fixed? If so, how can I get the colored table.

It is worth to mention that I am using the `tabu`enviroment as I will be using the columns with custom lengths `X[n]`. Is there any other alternative to `tabu` where I can set up the length of the columns?

Comment: You could switch to the `tabularx`  package.

Comment: @leandriis I am not aware of an easy way of set custom column width with the `tabularx` package

Comment: Changing the column width of `tabularx` `X` type columns can be done using `>{\hsize=2\hsize}X` see for example: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/337578/134144

Comment: No the problem hasn't been fixed. Read carefully the readme of the github you mentioned before continuing to use tabu.

Answer (score 5):

like this?

[image]

Why not use `tabu` package is explained in comments below your question ...

Solution can be use `tabularx` instead of `tabu` and `boldline` for horizontal lines with adjusted thickness (instead `booktabs` rules, which have (white) space above/below rule):

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{boldline}% for rules, part of Shipunov bundle
\usepackage{tabularx}
\newcolumntype{C}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}X}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\newcounter{tblerows}% see https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/297345/
                     % why-is-the-start-row-of-rowcolors-ignored-in-tabularx
\expandafter\let\csname c@tblerows\endcsname\rownum

\begin{document}
\begin{table}
    \rowcolors{2}{red!30}{blue!30}
    \begin{tabularx}{0.5\linewidth}{>{\hsize=1.5\hsize}C
                                    >{\hsize=0.5\hsize}C
                                    }
        \hlineB{2}
        Row1 & AA AA \\
        Row2 & B \\
        Row3 & C \\
        \hlineB{2}
    \end{tabularx}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 5):

The same question has been submitted in *GitHub*, see [Simplest MWE to have an alternating row color #18](https://github.com/tabu-fixed/tabu/issues/18). The proposed solution for the version `v2.9 2019/01/11` of `tabu`  comments some commands, see [Figure](https://github.com/meneldal/tabu/commit/2318a9d45800bd0f100022b44bad63c71a831f3d#diff-67337af7d77f6aaa90c39b744c246c6f). For further details, please check the solution provided in `GitHub`.

[image]

I try this fix in `tabu.sty` (`v2.9`) and does what you are looking for. Maybe it will be fixed in the next release of `tabu`.

In any case, please consider the above remark of [Ulrike Fisher](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/2388/ulrike-fischer) and thus the solution proposed by [Zarco](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/18189/zarko).