# Using cellcolor with tabu

Tags: tabu, colortbl, cell

I have made the following table:

```
\usepackage{tabu}
\usepackage{xcolor,colortbl}

\begin{center}
{\tabulinesep=1.2mm 
    \begin{tabu} to 0.9\linewidth { |[2pt] *{3}{X[1 c]|}[2pt] }
        \tabucline[2pt]{-}
        \cellcolor{green!20}\textbf{Parameter} & \cellcolor{green!20}\textbf{Value} & \cellcolor{green!20}\textbf{Units} \\ \tabucline[1.5pt]{-}
        \multicolumn{3}{ |[2pt]c|[2pt] }{\cellcolor{green!20}Nose Parameters} \\ \tabucline[2pt]{-}
        $\alpha$ & 10 & Deg \\ \tabucline[2pt]{-}
        \multicolumn{3}{ |[2pt]c|[2pt] }{\cellcolor{green!20}Body Parameters} \\ \tabucline[2pt]{-}
        $d_{B}$ & 122 & mm \\ \hline
        $L_{B}$ & 2670 & mm \\ \tabucline[2pt]{-}
    \end{tabu}}
\end{center}
```

[image]

However the title cells arent get affected by `\cellcolor`.

I have tried to update the package as I read it might effect but it did not work.

Thank you.

Comment: see https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/494689/color-rows-on-table-tabu-package if it can help you. Recent fix available on GitHub seems not yet be released on CTAN.

Answer (score 2):

The new LaTeX3 package [`tabularray`](https://ctan.org/pkg/tabularray) is an alternative to the outdated `tabu` package:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tabularray}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\begin{document}

\begin{center}
  \begin{tblr}{
    width = 0.9\linewidth,
    colspec = {|[2pt]X[1,c]|X[1,c]|X[1,c]|[2pt]},
    row{1} = {green9, font=\bfseries},
  }
    \hline[2pt]
      Parameter & Value & Units \\
    \hline[1.5pt]
      \SetCell[c=3]{c,green9} Nose Parameters & & \\
    \hline[2pt]
      $\alpha$ & 10 & Deg \\
    \hline[2pt]
      \SetCell[c=3]{c,green9} Body Parameters & &  \\
    \hline[2pt]
      $d_{B}$ & 122 & mm \\
    \hline
      $L_{B}$ & 2670 & mm \\
    \hline[2pt]
    \end{tblr}
\end{center}

\end{document}
```

[image]